# How do you perform the Festival Platform creative finisher?

Tags: senran-kagura-estival-versus

Festival Platforms are meant to be destroyed, but some of them have the creative finisher sign next to them. Despite KOing an opponent in front of the platforms multiple times, I've never seen the finisher happen.

Is there another requirement for the finisher? How do you perform it?
Additionally, it seems the creative finisher signs disappear when replaying an older mission, even if the platforms are still up. Just a visual bug or did I miss my chance for that mission?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not as obvious with other creative finishers, but the loser needs to be **in front** of the sign in order to activate the cutscene. Since festival platforms tend to be in the middle of a stage, it's easy to mistakenly believe you're close enough to trigger the finisher, while you're actually standing behind the sign.

As for the signs disappearing, replaying the mission again made the signs come back too, but I'm not sure if the signs are required for the finisher or not.